# Android : Facebook app id showing error in values-ta/strings.xml and can't able to generate signed apk

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using facebook login in my app. I've created facebook app id. If I use facebook app id in values/strings.xml it works fine and I'm able to generate signed apk in android studio. If I use that facebook app id in values-ta/strings.xml and values-de/strings.xml it shows an error and I'm not able to generate apk.

> **Error:** Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found variation in ta.
>
> Elements in the manifest can reference resources, but those resources cannot vary across configurations (except as a special case, by version, and except for a few specific package attributes such as the application title and icon.)

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not change the resource id for either the facebook app id or your own strings?

Comment: Actually I've this issue now with `android:description` attribute, I've string.xml in English and Arabic as well. If I removed the Arabic string it will work fine. I'm using Android Studio version `1.5.1` and I can't generate signed APK version.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is we need to add attribute `translatable="false"` in that particular string resource.

Comment: I tried to use the string hard coded in manifest.xml without using string file. But it didn't work. It's surprising.

Comment: This doesn't help at all, at least, in Android Studio 3.5.

Answer (score 8):

in android manifest change to this

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
        tools:ignore="ManifestResource" />
```

from :  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194705