# Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, manifest

When I want to insert the follow meta-tag:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.android.systemui.action_assist_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

I get the error message:

> `Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration
>    (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found variation in hdpi,
>    mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using a drawable resource instead of a mipmap resource.

Comment: I tried it, it shows as well the same error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Variation of resources in AndroidManifest.xml is detected as error.

It may be ignored like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          ...>

    ...

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.android.systemui.action_assist_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            tools:ignore="ManifestResource" />

   ...

</manifest>
```

see:
[Android : Facebook app id showing error in values-ta/strings.xml and can't able to generate signed apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388688/android-facebook-app-id-showing-error-in-values-ta-strings-xml-and-cant-able)

Answer (score 0):

I moved such strings to globalstrings.xml and removed the references from the locale files.