# Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration?

Tags: java, android, manifest

In my Manifest.xml, I get the following error:

```
Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found variation in hdpi, hdpi-v11, mdpi, mdpi-v11, xhdpi, xhdpi-v11, xxhdpi, xxhdpi-v11, xxxhdpi, xxxhdpi-v11
```

It seems to be complaining about two resources:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_no_notifications" />
```

and

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.yitter.android.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Should I put these two images in my no-dpi folder? It seems like it's complaining about the fact that there are variations in each resource group. What should I do?

I feel like `tools:ignore="ManifestResource"` (see here: [Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423503/resources-referenced-from-the-manifest-cannot-vary-by-configuration)) doesn't actually solve the problem, if there is one, and just band-aids it.

**Update:**

And in fact causes a build error...

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> D:\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:77:9-84:20: Error: Invalid instruction 'targetApi', valid instructions are : REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools:ignore="ManifestResource" into your meta-data tag.
If the error occurs for other files such as arrays.xml then use translatable="false"