# Error while generating APK

Tags: android-studio, google-play, apk

I'm trying to generate an APK from Android Studio for publish it on the play store.
Now when i generate the APK i got this error:

[image]
**I can start the app but "Generate APK" not work** and for avoid this error i copy my Facebook App Id from my string.xml to my manifest:

```
android:value="2132153153153535"
```

Instead of:

```
android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
```

Now i can generate the APK but when i launch my app from the playstore i got this error:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stable.giamma.sushichallenge/com.stable.giamma.sushichallenge.MenuActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Both context and applicationId must be non-null

That i can resolve by reversing the modify that i just did.

But if i do so i can't generate the APK again.....

**What is the right way for handle the "facebook app id" and generate the APK?**

p.s: i have 2 string.xml (one is for english and the other for italian language) dunno if create some problem...

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.asd.appname">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
o
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/asd"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />   //THIS IS THE STRING THAT I MODIFY FOR AVOID THE FIRST ERROR

    <activity
        android:name="com.asd.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.asd.MenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.asd.SushataActivity"
        android:label="@string/sushata"
        android:parentActivityName="com.asd.MenuActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.asd.MenuActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.asd.Sushata2Activity"
        android:label="@string/sushata2"
        android:parentActivityName="com.asd.SushataActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.asd.SushataActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.asd.Leaderboard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Show your *manifest code*.

Comment: Have you tried defining *meta-data tag* at the end i mean below *LeaderBoard Activity*. Give a try.

Comment: yea same error, cant generate apk

Comment: i  updated the first error with more line

Comment: Have you initialized *facebook sdk* in your *Activity* ?

Comment: Yes -  'code' protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

Comment: Try by adding this `AppEventsLogger.activateApp(yourcontext);` below `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize` will might work.

Comment: added but still not able to generate the apk

Comment: Then you need to trace your problem because the possibilities this much only i know to solve when i got the same issue and do *invalidate/caches and restart studio* once and then try.

Comment: I added the error screen, also i did clean project and restart Android Studio but still not work "generate apk"

Comment: May be because you have 2 *strings.xml* with different language so make sure for facebook id the key name will remains the same don't give that different for both *xml*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added:

`tools:ignore="ManifestResource"`

The correct code is:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
        tools:ignore="ManifestResource"/>
```

Now seems work I found this stackoverflow post helpful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388688/android-facebook-app-id-showing-error-in-values-ta-strings-xml-and-cant-able)